# Add --density flag to libvips command with image_processing?

Tags: ruby, image-processing, shrine

I'm trying to add the [--density](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/issues/379#issuecomment-181283691) flag to the libvips command so that PDFs (or other vector images) convert to JPG at an acceptable resolution.

Context—before I upgraded to a recent version of image_processing, I was using MiniMagick with the older version and was able to add arbitrary flags using this code:

```
  MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |convert|
    convert << "-verbose" 
    convert << "-background" << "white"
    convert << "-flatten"
    convert << "-density" << "300"
    convert << page.path          
    convert << "-quality" << "82"
    convert << page_image.path
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think libvips equivalent of ImageMagick `-density` is the `:dpi` option on [`vips_pdfload()`](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-pdfload). With `image_processing` gem you can set it via `loader`:

```
require "image_processing/vips"

ImageProcessing::Vips
  .source(image)
  .loader(dpi: 300)
  .saver(quality: 82)
  # ...
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I just added it to the github wiki.